# Error while Running Jasper report in Jasper Server with Report Parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report with parameter called - CustometID

I want to pass this value to the where clause. So i have changed my SQL query as below :

SELECT * FROM JSW_LOCATION_MASTER WHERE ID_NO=$P{CustometID}

if I preview the report from Jasper Studio, Input controll is coming and after entering data, report is generated successfully.

After that I published the report in Jasper Server and created a Input Controll called - CustometID and mapped to report.

if i run report, its giving below error :

2018-02-21 23:21:20,166 ERROR AsyncJasperPrintAccessor,pool-6-thread-20:321 - Error during report execution
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: CrossCheck

## Links:

JRXML Gist link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85ee2e3ee09952b6d8f3d1875b51096a
Logfile : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/55b56496b3df5b3b12d66cfb0b9688d0

Could you anybody please help me out. I facing this problem from couple of days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding schema name before table or stored procedure name in JRXML file.

From the stored procedure we are invoking a DB View. I have added schema name before view name also.

Thank you all.